# After successful authentication token is not authenticated

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony-3.2, symfony-security

I'm new in Symfony 3.2. I need to implement form authentication. User fetches from database. After `post` to `/login` `onAuthenticationSuccess` event fires, but token is still unauthenticate:[image]

**What i am doing wrong?**

---

*security.yml*

```
security:

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            iterations: 10

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_DEVELOPER: ROLE_ADMIN


    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        dvm_db_provider:
            entity:
               class: AppBundle:User

firewalls:        
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: true
        pattern: ^/
        guard:
            authenticators: [dvm.authenticator]

        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        logout: ~
        provider: dvm_db_provider

access_control:
```

---

*User.php*

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection; 
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface {

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surname;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="patronymic", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $patronymic;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="date")
     */
    private $birthday;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $gender;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="avatar", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $avatar;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $plainPass;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pass_hash", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $passHash;
    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles", joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlainPass() {
        return $this->plainPass;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $plainPass
     */
    public function setPlainPass($plainPass) {
        $this->plainPass = $plainPass;
        $this->passHash = password_hash($this->plainPass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {
        $this->setPlainPass('');
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname() {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSurname($surname) {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get patronymic
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPatronymic() {
        return $this->patronymic;
    }

    /**
     * Set patronymic
     *
     * @param string $patronymic
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPatronymic($patronymic) {
        $this->patronymic = $patronymic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get birthday
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthday() {
        return $this->birthday;
    }

    /**
     * Set birthday
     *
     * @param \DateTime $birthday
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setBirthday($birthday) {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get gender
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGender() {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * Set gender
     *
     * @param string $gender
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGender($gender) {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get avatar
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAvatar() {
        return $this->avatar;
    }

    /**
     * Set avatar
     *
     * @param string $avatar
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAvatar($avatar) {
        $this->avatar = $avatar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsBlocked($isActive) {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize([$this->id, $this->name, $this->surname, $this->patronymic, $this->getPassword(), $this->isActive, $this->email]);
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->getPassHash();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassHash() {
        return $this->passHash;
    }

    public function getSalt() {
        return null;
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list($this->id, $this->name, $this->surname, $this->patronymic, $this->passHash, $this->isActive, $this->email)
                = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
        return $this->getUsername() === $user->getUsername()
                && $this->getPassword() === $user->getPassword();
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles() {
        $rolesArray = [];
        /* @var $role Role */
        foreach ($this->roles->toArray() as $role) $rolesArray[] = $role->getName();
        return $rolesArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $roles
     */
    public function setRoles($roles) {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function isEnabled() {
        return $this->getIsActive();
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsActive() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setPassword($pass) {
        $this->setPlainPass($pass);
    }
}
```

---

*Authenticator.php*

```
class Authenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator {

    public function getCredentials(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/login' || !$request->isMethod('POST')) return null;
        return ['u' => $request->get('_username'), 'p' => $request->get('_password')];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider) {
        if (!$credentials['u']) return null;
        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['u']);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user) {
        if (!password_verify($credentials['p'], $user->getPassword())) {
            dump([$credentials['p'], $user->getPassword()], password_verify($credentials['p'], $user->getPassword()));
            die;
        }
        if (!$credentials['p']) return null;
        return password_verify($credentials['p'], $user->getPassword());
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        dump(__FUNCTION__);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey) {
        dump(__FUNCTION__);
        $token->setAuthenticated(true);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe() {
        return false;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null) {
        return new RedirectResponse('/login');
    }

}
```

---

*Security_log*

```
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"...@mail.ru","provider":"Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Security\\User\\EntityUserProvider"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard configurator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Passing guard token information to the GuardAuthenticationProvider {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.INFO: Guard authentication successful! {"token":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken: PostAuthenticationGuardToken(user=\"....@mail.ru\", authenticated=true, roles=\"ROLE_DEVELOPER\"))","authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator set success response. {"response":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\RedirectResponse: HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nCache-Control: no-cache, private\r\nDate:          Thu, 25 May 2017 23:38:03 GMT\r\nLocation:      /\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n        <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=/\" />\n\n        <title>Redirecting to /</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        Redirecting to <a href=\"/\">/</a>.\n    </body>\n</html>)","authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Remember me skipped: it is not configured for the firewall. {"authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: The "AppBundle\Security\DvmAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called {"authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:03] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:04] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:04] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"...@mail.ru","provider":"Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Security\\User\\EntityUserProvider"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:04] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:04] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard configurator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"AppBundle\\Security\\DvmAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-26 09:38:04] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-05-26 09:41:56] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
```

Comment: You don't need `$token->setAuthenticated(true);` in `onAuthenticationSuccess` (_user here is already authenticated and the token was set authomatically by Symfony_). Instead you should return a `RedirectResponse` (_to the homepage or user dashboard as example or whetever you want_).

Comment: @gp_sflover, thx, but it is not a reason of that failure, i've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this function is making the problem with authentication because returns `false` in your case.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
    return $this->getUsername() === $user->getUsername()
            && $this->getPassword() === $user->getPassword();
}
```

Please try to just compare the `id`.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->id === $user->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onAuthenticationSuccess just return null.

And stick to this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: I had done everything like in this tutorial at the begining, and it did not work. And that code is my further experements.